# Python Selenium Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.000 (why)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have seen multiple issues with the same title but none helped me. Possible resons I believe are:

1. Version of ChromeDriver
2. the time specified in the message (Others had different float nos at the end of the msg and it varied each time they ran the script)

I constantly get this error with -0.000.

I tried the same script with 2 different versions of browsers and chromedrivers (88 and 89).

Error trace:

```
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-2f4bc7db8eb8> in <module>
----> 1 main("Mumbai","email","passwd")

<ipython-input-12-fa2408c70274> in main(city, email, passwd)
     21         for j in range(0,len(sub_cat)):
     22             category_name,driver1, num1,n_av1 = bb_addcart(driver,cat,sub_cat[j])
---> 23             p_cat,driver1 =parse_cart(driver1,category_name)
     24             if(cc==1):
     25                 data= p_cat

<ipython-input-9-b1fd03820d1f> in parse_cart(driver, df2)
      1 def parse_cart(driver,df2):
      2     masterarray = np.array(["brand","prod_name","unit_col","f_price","mrp","price","discount","quantity","datetime","prod_id"])
----> 3     driver.get('https://www.bigbasket.com/basket/?ver=1')
      4     time.sleep(5)
      5     html = driver.page_source

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    332         """
--> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    334 
    335     @property

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.000
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)
```

Note: The same code worked perfectly fine with version 86, 87, and 88 in Beta on a different system a few months ago. Please suggest possible fix.

**The code works perfectly fine for approx 1 to 2 hours and I get this error only after the script has ran for a very long time. The max execution time of my script is 3.5 hrs.**

Comment: Your code trials please.

Comment: anyone please help...

Comment: I would be interested in this too - having the same issues. Looked everywhere and tried almost everything.